# Exec batch file not run with space in project folder

Tags: c#, file, batch-file, command, dos

I have a simple problem but I don't know how to handle this. That is: I have a simple batch file that remove all file in the folder (for example). I can run it in anywhere but I want to exec it by a application by C#. Everything is allright If the project folder doesn't contains spaces ("Example: `C:\Project Test\test.bat`" will be error" but "`C:\ProjectTest\test.bat`" is done").

Below is my source code to run (I say it again: It only error if project folder contain space in folder names). Not error when run file batch if project folder not have space.

```
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "D:\\prepare.bat";
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\";
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        myProcess.Start();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
        MessageBox.Show(myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments + " " + myString);
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting script path in quotes:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"D:\\Project Test\\prepare.bat\"";
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Same to Chilaka Umesh

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your arguments in quotes like this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Project Test\\test.bat\""
```

or

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\"C:\Project Test\test.bat\""
```

When passed to cmd the arguments must be quoted.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Same to Chilaka Umesh.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `"C:\Project Test\test.bat"` use `"\"C:\Project Test\test.bat\""`